# Join split string with mysql table

Tags: mysql, split, left-join

I have two MySQL tables

> [client_data] and [default_values]

As shown below:

Client_Data table

[image: Client Data]

Default_Values

[image: Default Values]

**My Question is :**

I want to view client_data table with joining default_values table c_value.string[split(1)]. How to do this?

See sample below;

[image: Gen_Data]

Comment: Please post plain text, not images, so we can copy and paste into sqlfiddle demos.

Comment: Doesn't the `SUBSTRING_INDEX` function do what you want?

Comment: here's a fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/445c2. Your question isn't a question, it's a work order. Where can I send my invoice?

Comment: I am sorry for giving pictures. [here is my sql](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/445c2/6).
As you can see, it is giving Type and Nationality as INT values. I want to get it from default_values and show string according to INT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by joining with `default_values` twice. I use a `LEFT JOIN` so it includes results for clients that don't have matching data in `default_values` (because you left out Philipines in your sqlfiddle).

```
SELECT client_id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(v2.c_value, ',', -1) AS type, SUBSTRING_INDEX(v1.c_value, ',', -1) AS nationality
FROM client_data AS c
LEFT JOIN default_values AS v1 ON c.nationality = SUBSTRING_INDEX(v1.c_value, ',', 1) AND v1.category = 'Nationality'
LEFT JOIN default_values AS v2 ON c.type = SUBSTRING_INDEX(v2.c_value, ',', 1) AND v2.category = 'c_type'
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b614c/2)

Answer (score 0):

This should work...i tried this on sql server. please look at the function equivalent of substring, charindex and len in mysql

```
select 
    client_id,cvalue as type, nvalue as nationality
from 
    client_data,
    (select
        category,
        substring(c_value,1, charindex(',',c_value)-1) as nindex, 
        substring(c_value,charindex(',',c_value)+1,len(c_value)) as nvalue
    from 
        default_values
    where category = 'Nationality') nTable,

    (select
        category,
        substring(c_value,1, charindex(',',c_value)-1) as cindex, 
        substring(c_value,charindex(',',c_value)+1,len(c_value)) as cvalue
    from 
        default_values
    where category = 'c_type') cTable
Where client_data.type = cTable.cindex AND client_data.nationality = nTable.nindex
```

Comment: There is a problem with your charindex command. Please check it. Anyway [Mr.Barmar](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) has given me perfect answer. You can look in to it as well. Thnaks for your reply as well